# Filter for namespaced controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, actionpack

I have a set of controllers in the folder /controllers/admin that all look like this and having the same `filter`:

```
module Admin
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :some_method

    #actions
  end
end
```

How could each namespaced controller inherit the `before_action :some_method` from a central place?

Comment: The class is essentially the same as **Admin::UsersController**, so you can have other controllers nested from that like *class Admin::RestrictedUsersController < Admin::UsersController*.

Comment: Ah sorry. What I meant was that I have 8 "admin-controllers" already with that exact `filter` - is there any way to extract it and let all 8 controllers inherit it from one single place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need an individual Base controller within Admin module namespace:

```
class Admin::BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :some_method

  #actions
end

class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
  #some_method filter is invoked here
end

class Admin::PostsController < Admin::BaseController
  #some_method filter is invoke here
end
```